# XML RSS image displaying in PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom, rss, rss-reader

Im trying to pull an image URL out of an RSS link.

Here's an image of one of the items inside there.

[image]

In the image there is an tag `media:thumbnail`

I am using this for the title, link and discription:

```
$item_title = $item->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$item_link = $item->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$item_desc = $item->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

However I cannot seem to pull out the `media:thumbnail`.

I have tried the same as the other one's

```
$item_img = $item->getElementsByTagName('media:thumbnail')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

But this gives me this error: 
[image]

Line 24 is the line that I tried. but I also tried using `.attribute(url)` but this also doesnt return a thing.

I hope someone can help me with this, its been 4 hours since I got this problem but after a lot of try and error there wasnt a single time I got the URL back.

Thanks in advance, and happy coding.

Comment: For completeness can you perhaps post an actual textual code snippet of the XML, in stead of an image (certainly next time you post another question)? It makes creating a quick test much easier for people that want to help you. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `media:` part on elements in your XML, is called a [namespace prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Namespaces) and represents a namespace URI. You should be able to find this URI as the value of a `xmlns:media` attribute on one of the `media:` element's ancestors. If you can't find that, you should be able to use the URI value of the `xmlns` attribute on the element itself (if applicable, which in this case it *is*).

In order to fetch certain elements from a certain namespace you should then use that namespace's URI and call [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagNameNS()`](http://php.net/manual/domelement.getelementsbytagnamens.php) instead of [`DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/manual/domelement.getelementsbytagname.php), like so:

```
$item_img = $item->getElementsByTagNameNS('the namespace URI you found','thumbnail')
                 ->item(0)
                 ->childNodes
                 ->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

If you don't care about what namespace a particular element is defined in, you could just keep using `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName()`, but leave out the namespace prefix:

```
$item_img = $item->getElementsByTagName('thumbnail')
                 ->item(0)
                 ->childNodes
                 ->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Be aware though that this will fetch *all* `<thumbnail>` elements, no matter what namespace they are in.

However, in the sample XML you've shown<sup>1</sup>, the `<media:thumbnail>` element does not have any child nodes, so the above examples of your code that I adjusted will still fail.

Lastly, `.attribute(url)` is just invalid syntax. It should be [`->getAttribute('url')`](http://php.net/manual/domelement.getattribute.php), of course.

So, to wrap it up, you should be able to get the `url` attribute of the first `<thumbnail>` of a particular namespace with:

```
$item_img = $item->getElementsByTagNameNS('the namespace URI you found','thumbnail')
                 ->item(0)->getAttribute('url');
```

or:

```
$item_img = $item->getElementsByTagName('thumbnail')
                 ->item(0)->getAttribute('url');
```

if you don't care about the namespace of the element.

---

<sup>1) Please post actual sample XML code next time, instead of an image.</sup>

Comment: A more perfect answer doesnt exist. Thank you it worked. and also thanks for the explanation about what I did wrong!!